# Class variable reference itself?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I am new to coding period (3-ish weeks) and have been building and rebuilding a RPG to help teach myself the principles that I have been learning. However, I seem to be stuck on one specific aspect of Python classes.

A class variable I have created for my `worldLocation` class reads as such where the `NORTH`, `EAST`, `SOUTH`, `WEST` all reference strings:

```
WHITEROOM = worldLocation('A Plain White Room',
                          '...\n\nWhere are you?\n\n'
                          'All around you is white...\n\n'
                          '...only white...',
                          [ROCK.GROUNDDESC],
                          [RAT.NAME],
                          {NORTH: 'A Plain White Room',
                           SOUTH: 'A Plain White Room',
                           EAST: 'A Plain White Room',
                           WEST: 'A Plain White Room'})
```

But I want it to instead read like this, where each of the instance variables references the class variable itself:

```
WHITEROOM = worldLocation('A Plain White Room',
                          '...\n\nWhere are you?\n\n'
                          'All around you is white...\n\n'
                          '...only white...',
                          [ROCK.GROUNDDESC],
                          [RAT.NAME],
                          {NORTH: WHITEROOM,
                           SOUTH: WHITEROOM,
                           EAST: WHITEROOM,
                           WEST: WHITEROOM})
```

However, every time I attempt to change it to the latter, I receive an `undefined name WHITEROOM` error. What am I doing wrong or missing?

The class code is as follows:

```
class worldLocation(object):
    def __init__(self, NAME, DESC, GROUND, ENEMIES, DIRECTIONS):
        self.NAME = NAME
        self.DESC = DESC
        self.GROUND = GROUND
        self.ENEMIES = ENEMIES
        self.DIRECTIONS = DIRECTIONS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you want to use is trying to reference the instance in a dictionary being passed as argument to `__init__()` *before* it exists. That's not feasible (and arguably really reasonable if you think about it).

However, you can workaround the issue by creating a special value that the class initializer `__init__()` method can check for and fix-up the data being passed.

Below is code illustrating what I mean. *Note* I've added some scaffolding at the beginning to make it runnable for testing purposes.

```
#### Some scaffolding for testing.
NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST = 'NORTH SOUTH EAST WEST'.split()

class ROCK:
    GROUNDDESC = 'ground desc'

class RAT:
    NAME = 'Ricky'
####


class WorldLocation:
    THIS = object()  # A unique value.

    def __init__(self, NAME, DESC, GROUND, ENEMIES, DIRECTIONS):
        self.NAME = NAME
        self.DESC = DESC
        self.GROUND = GROUND
        self.ENEMIES = ENEMIES

        # Replace any values in DIRECTIONS dictionary argument that refer to the
        # instance being created (as designated by them being the class
        # attribute THIS).
        self.DIRECTIONS = {direction: self if value is self.THIS else value
                               for direction, value in DIRECTIONS.items()}


WHITEROOM = WorldLocation('A Plain White Room',
                          '...\n\nWhere are you?\n\n'
                          'All around you is white...\n\n'
                          '...only white...',
                          [ROCK.GROUNDDESC],
                          [RAT.NAME],
                          {NORTH: WorldLocation.THIS,
                           SOUTH: WorldLocation.THIS,
                           EAST: WorldLocation.THIS,
                           WEST: WorldLocation.THIS})

# Show that it works.
from pprint import pprint

print(f'id(WHITEROOM): 0x{id(WHITEROOM):08x}\n')
pprint(vars(WHITEROOM))
```

Sample output:

```
id(WHITEROOM): 0x010d0390

{'DESC': '...\n'
         '\n'
         'Where are you?\n'
         '\n'
         'All around you is white...\n'
         '\n'
         '...only white...',
 'DIRECTIONS': {'EAST': <__main__.WorldLocation object at 0x010D0390>,
                'NORTH': <__main__.WorldLocation object at 0x010D0390>,
                'SOUTH': <__main__.WorldLocation object at 0x010D0390>,
                'WEST': <__main__.WorldLocation object at 0x010D0390>},
 'ENEMIES': ['Ricky'],
 'GROUND': ['ground desc'],
 'NAME': 'A Plain White Room'}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the purpose of the `.This` variable/attribute. Why would I use that particular argument instead of simply adding the dictionary items I need?

Comment: @Joshuah: That particular item is something unique defined by the class so it can be referenced (and recognized as such) when doing the second part of the initialization in the derived class' `__init__()`. Since it's not used until after the class has been defined, it avoids the issue of trying to reference the instance before it has been created. Think of it as a "placeholder"..

Comment: I think I understand what you are attempting to say, but I will have to run the code myself both with and without that particular line to grasp exactly what it is for.

Comment: @Joshuah: Didn't know you were asking about a particular line. Because of how name look-ups work in Python inside a class, `self.THIS` is equivalent to `WorldLocation.THIS` in this usage case, so it's a reference to the class attribute. I prefer the former because it avoids hardcoding the class' name into the code — i.e. so will continue to work automatically if you rename of class (and because it's shorter). Anyway, the code is checking each value in the dictionary being passed, and if it has this special value, replaces it with a reference to the instance that's being created.

Comment: Makes sense. Took me a moment to grasp the concept, but once I understood what exactly the code was saying by `self.DIRECTIONS = {direction: self if value is self.THIS else value for direction, value in DIRECTIONS.items()}` it all started to come together. I like having this option, though I may end up using a combination of this method and @Barmar 's method until I see which one works best to minimize the amount of code I end up needing to write.

Comment: @Joshuah: Well, my answer requires more LOC than @Barmar's because it requires defining a base class first to support the workaround — but that's relatively simple and only needs to be done once. To make it more intelligible, you could change the name of `THIS` to `SELF` (or something else more suitable) if you wished.

Comment: What I meant was your answer does exactly what I asked, yes - and to a T, however it then leaves me lacking in being able to then reference other 'rooms' via the variables that are being created. i.e., whichever variable/room which is lower will be able to reference all variables/rooms above it, but any variables/rooms placed above others in code will only be able reference variables/rooms above them. In order to solve THAT issue, I will end up ALSO having to use @Barmar's solution to create a catchall list of `WORLDlocations = []` and enter all created `worldLocation` class variables there.

Comment: Final code follows your `class` suggestion above, with the following changes suggested by @Barmar: a second variable for the room underneath all the rooms like such: `WHITEROOM.DIRECTIONS = {SOUTH: BLACKROOM, EAST: REDROOM, NORTH: WHITEROOM, WEST: WHITEROOM}` and a final container variable like such to hold all rooms for movement purposes: `WORLDlocations = [WHITEROOM, REDROOM, BLUEROOM, BLACKROOM]`

Comment: @Joshuah: After thinking more about what you want to do (and getting a little sleep), I've simplified the code in my answer — the basic idea for the workaround is the same, but implementing it by creating a separate base class isn't necessary to implement it, so I removed that. Note also that you could have multiple placeholder values and substitute different things depending on which one was used — which might be useful (based on your latest comments).

Answer (score 0):

The variable doesn't get a value until after the function returns, so you can't refer to it in the arguments to the function. You have to add those references after you assign the variable.

```
WHITEROOM = worldLocation('A Plain White Room', '...\n\nWhere are you?\n\nAll around you is white...\n\n...only white...', [ROCK.GROUNDDESC], [RAT.NAME], {})
WHITEROOM.DIRECTIONS = {NORTH: WHITEROOM, SOUTH: WHITEROOM, EAST: WHITEROOM, WEST: WHITEROOM}
```

Comment: Seeing this, I don't know why I didn't think of this before. You do this with other kinds of variables, why wouldn't you do this for these as well! Adding the code this way does not currently create an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you want to accomplish, but you cannot reference a variable before it's declared.

So, for example, you cannot say `A={'key':A}` because until the `dict` is created, it cannot be used as a value for `'key'`.

Try this:

```
WHITEROOM = worldLocation('A Plain White Room', '...\n\nWhere are you?\n\nAll around you is white...\n\n...only white...', [ROCK.GROUNDDESC], [RAT.NAME], {})
WHITEROOM.DIRECTIONS = {NORTH: WHITEROOM, SOUTH: WHITEROOM, EAST: WHITEROOM, WEST: WHITEROOM}
```

Why does this work?  Well, the `worldLocation` constructor `__init__` will create the `worldLocation` object and assign it to the variable `WHITEROOM`.  Then we can access the `WHITEROOM.DIRECTIONS` variable with the dot operator and pass it a new `dict` that uses the `WHITEROOM` variable as a *reference* to the `WHITEROOM` object.
It's not as elegant as you'd like, but I think this way you'll be able to do what you're trying to do.